# The END (Riley riddle)

Tags: riddle, mathematics, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

> My prefix you say in astonishment,
>
> My infix within the prefix slightly smaller than a pie
>
> My suffix is huge, or even enormous,
>
> And here comes the end of the riddle.

Hint 1:

> The tag 'mathematics' is there for a reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My prefix you say in astonishment,

> **OM**e**G**a!

My infix within the prefix slightly smaller than a pie

> om**e**ga, because [2.7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)) is less than 3.1

My suffix is huge, or even enormous,

> o**mega**

And here comes the end of the riddle.

> OMG + e + mega = **omega**, which is the *end* of the Greek alphabet, and a constituent of the title (and username)!

Comment: Answer and suffix correct! Congrats! +1

Comment: But I’ll only accept ur answer if u get the other explanations right, keep it up!

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Oh. Ohhhhhhhhh!

Comment: Correct now :) Good

Answer (score 1):

I will give it another try.

Is it

> opifice?

Prefix

> "Oh" or "o" is the sound one makes when surprised/astonished.

Infix

> Pi is "smaller" (shorter) than Pie.

Suffix

> Fice is and old word synonym to feist. Feist = Gross, which is big in German. Also it is a synonym of obese.

Comment: Prefix and infix almost there, suffix wrong. Keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> atrocity?

Prefix

> Ah or a is the sound one makes when surprised/astonished.

Infix

> Three is smaller than number Pi. Three sounds like "tree" which is close to "tro"

Suffix

> Cities are bigger than villages or towns. Can be big/huge.

Comment: I see someone downvoted. Do you care to explain?

Comment: I didn't downvoted it, but sorry, you are wrong for all three of them. Give it another try! +1 for consolation